# why the DOMContentLoaded did not trigger in google chrome plugin

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have defined the DOMContentLoaded event in content script in google chrome plugin v3 like this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    debugger
    console.log("loaded...");
});
```

and the manifest.json defined like this:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "sniffer",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "host_permissions": [
    "*://*/*"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "serviceWorker.js",
    "type": "module"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "src/entries/popup/index.html"
  },
  "options_ui": {
    "page": "src/entries/options/index.html",
    "open_in_tab": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": [
        "src/entries/scripts/contentscript.js"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "*://*/*"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_idle"
    }
  ]
}
```

After I installed the plugin and refresh the web page, the content script did not trigger the events.  I can found the script from devtools:

[image]

Am I missing something? what should I do to trigger the events?

Comment: Because it runs after DOMContentLoaded, see the description of run_at in the documenation.

Comment: the DOMContentLoaded triggered before the content script load?

Comment: Yes, see the documentation for run_at.